# Project build error while creating Magnolia basic project using magnolia archyetype on linux

Tags: maven, magnolia

I built a magnolia project with the archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/
```

- Tried the latest (snapshot) version of the archetype
- Used Magnolia version 5.3.1

After the build I tried to import it in Spring Tool Suit while importing I got following error in `the pom.xml` :

```
Project build er:ror: Non-parseable POM /home/ruby/.m2/repository/info/magnolia/magnolia-parent-pom-ce/28/magnolia-parent-pom-ce-28.pom: end tag name </body> must match start tag name <hr> from line 7 (position: TEXT seen ...</address>\n</body>... @9:8) 
Project build error: Non-parseable POM /home/ruby/.m2/repository/info/magnolia/magnolia-parent-pom-ce/28/magnolia-parent-pom-ce-28.pom: end tag name </body> must match start tag name <hr> from line 7 (position: TEXT seen ...</address>\n</body>... @9:8)**
```

And while running this through  tomcat it is also unable to start  Magnolia, I got resource not available.

Comment: Please, post the file `/home/ruby/.m2/repository/info/magnolia/magnolia-parent-pom-ce/28/magnolia-parent-pom-ce-28.pom` (or paste somewhere like pastebin and post the link).

Comment: magnolia-parent-pom-ce-28.pom:

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/repositories/magnolia.public.releases/info/magnolia/magnolia-parent-pom-ce/28/magnolia-parent-pom-ce-28.pom">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at nexus.magnolia-cms.com Port 80</address>
<hr>
</body></html>

Comment: i have tried the whole process now through maven 3.2.3 got error in parent pom : Project build error: Invalid packaging for parent POM [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version], must be "pom" but is "jar"

Comment: If you see the parent is a `html` and not a `pom` file, this seems that your `.m2/repository` have the incorrect version, try removing `/home/ruby/.m2/repository/info/magnolia/` and run maven again.

Comment: i have removed /home/ruby/.m2/repository/info/magnolia/ and run maven again now i am not getting any error in pom but while running  acme-project-webapp through vmware vfabric in built web server in Spring Tool Suit i got resource not available ie it is not deploying the app , i have also done this process with tomcat .. i am reffering http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects#fn:2 post, according to this while running it should start magnolia but it is not doing that....

Answer (score 0):

Magnolia's maven Repository is only available over https, yet you specified http as a protocol, hence the 301 redirect and error.